# How do I select the top three rows in my database for posts

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a posting system along with a liking system. I wanted to select the top three posts with the most likes but I don't know how to do that.

I have this code but I can't figure out how to select more than just one row.

```
$get_pop_posts = mysql_query( "SELECT MAX( likes ) AS popular_posts FROM `posts`;" );
while($fetch_pop_posts = mysql_fetch_array($get_pop_posts)){
    $pop_posts = $fetch_pop_posts['popular_posts'];

    echo $pop_posts;
}
```

this piece of code only fetches one row from the database.

Comment: Googling your title brought so many results, it even made my head spin.

Comment: Do read on [`SELECT()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-select-query.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM posts
order by likes desc
limit 3
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT MAX( likes ) AS popular_posts FROM `posts`

This query return single result because of the function MAX().

Try this 
SELECT TOP 3 FROM posts

Answer (score 0):

Firstly give unique id to each post that should be incremented automatically each time a new post comes.

Then,
SELECT id FROM posts order by likes desc limit 3

Pass these id's as arrays to get the complete post.